# Separate Dextrose & Caffeine in water?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility

Can a dextrose / caffeine powder be (mostly) separated by dissolving in water then filtering the water?

Dextrose is readily soluble in water (1-10 parts solvent to 1 part solute).
Caffeine anhydrous is sparingly soluble in water (30-100 water : 1 caffeine).

I'm assuming water would dissolve nearly all the dextrose (and a bit of caffeine), and upon reaching saturation, the caffeine will remain out of solution in solid form and easily filtered.

Repeating the process would refine (increase) the quantity of caffeine vs. dextrose in the remaining filtered solids.

Thoughts?

References:

[Caffeine Anhydrous - BASF](http://www.pharma-ingredients.basf.com/Statements/Technical%20Informations/EN/Pharma%20Solutions/03_030708e_Caffeine%20anhydrous.pdf)

[Dextrose - NBS](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ScientificPapers/nbsscientificpaper437vol17p715_A2b.pdf)

Comment: Yes, exploiting differences in solubility is indeed one of the easiest ways to separate compounds - however in practice I suspect a chemist would use more "sophisticated" methods (not sure exactly what, maybe column chromatography) since dissolving it in water leads to quite a bit of product loss.

Comment: Non - polar solvent extraction  would be a good method.

Comment: @Joel any household ingredients that could do that?

Comment: @Baker , I don't know what you have at your house! I suggest to study the chemistry involved in a non-polar extraction of alkaloids then you should be able to sort it out...